# Searching using regular expression for a word of set length with but with half random characters

Tags: notepad++

I'm trying to figure out how to write a macro for Notepad++ and the first problem I have encountered is trying to write a regular expression that will find an unique record key.

090052fb814c0f10

090052fb

The Keys are 16 characters long, and all begin with the same 8 characters.

I guess the search method will depend on what I'm wanting to happen next... well I am hoping to perform a find replace on particular carriage returns using the position of this unique key as a reference point.

So if I can at least get the key to be searchable at all that is a start!

Possibly using the =? pattern search...

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOTE: Since you seem to work with hex numbers, I'm using [0-9a-fA-F] for the matches:

Try with this:

`\b090052fb\K[a-fA-F0-9]{8}`

Remember to tick "Regular expression" on the find popup on notepad++

`\b` Matches bareword, so it will make you find `090052fb` that It is not preceeded by any other numbers or letters.

`\K` ignores the previous matches

`{8}` repeat 8 times.

Example: https://regex101.com/r/WccN2S/3

If the prefix is not always the same, you may use this instead:

`\b[a-fA-F0-9]{8}\K[a-fA-F0-9]{8}`

https://regex101.com/r/WccN2S/2/

Comment: on a side note: is this regex stuff hated so much that it gets downvoted on sight? Some of my friends described it as Arcane Majicks

Comment: @HotSauceCoconuts I don't think so. At least for me, regular expressions are fun (yeah, I know) I think the downvote was because the question could have been better written. Several lines of input and expected output is always welcome on regexp questions. Also, It is always a good idea (if not a requirement) to always say what things have you tried.